# How to bring a view to the front on tapping them? ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, view, gesture-recognition

I am creating an instance of an image view every time a button is pressed. The last instance created is brought to the front. How do I bring a different instance to the front by tapping on it?

```
- (void) hatsPressed {
NSLog(@"HAT PRESSED");
hat2Image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 50, 100, 100)];
hat2Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hat2"];
[self.view addSubview:hat2Image];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:hat2Image];
hat2Image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
[hat2Image addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[hat2Image addGestureRecognizer:_hat2Pan];
[hat2Image addGestureRecognizer:_hat2Pinch];
[hat2Image addGestureRecognizer:_hat2Rotate];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do it...
Add a gesture recognizer to each of the image view you instantiate.
The handler of that gesture needs to call a delegate method in the super view or controller where the image views are added to.

When calling that delegate in your controller or view just call

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTappedView];
```

*I'd recycle the image views... creating one for each tap is not a very good way to do it.

let me know if you need some more details.